# Установка Realplexor-а

Tags: linux

Использую инструкцию из примера:

```
cd /opt
wget http://github.com/DmitryKoterov/dklab_realplexor/tarball/master
tar zxf *realplexor*.tar.gz
mv *realplexor*/ dklab_realplexor
# Now deal with an init-script.
ln -s /opt/dklab_realplexor/dklab_realplexor.init /etc/init.d/dklab_realplexor
chkconfig --add dklab_realplexor
chkconfig dklab_realplexor on
service dklab_realplexor start
```

Дохожу до шага `chkconfig --add dklab_realplexor` и получаю сообщение об ошибке:

```
[dklab_realplexor]# chkconfig dklab_realplexor on
error reading information on service dklab_realplexor: No such file or directory
```

Проверка на:

```
yum install chkconfig
```

дает результат:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Setting up Install Process
Package chkconfig-1.3.49.3-2.el6_4.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Система: CentOS 6.4

Файл `/etc/init.d/dklab_realplexor` есть - но пустой. Открыл так:

```
vim /etc/init.d/dklab_realplexor`
```

Comment: /opt/dklab_realplexor/dklab_realplexor.init пустой ?

Comment: Не моё, но Игоря Бабичева, авось поможет: http://blog.himic.ru/Perl/2010/08/13/dklab_realplexor-nastroyka-chast-5.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

команда `wget http://github.com/DmitryKoterov/dklab_realplexor/tarball/master` сохранит в текущем каталоге файл под именем `master`, соответственно, следующая за ней команда распаковки архива `tar ...` ничего не распакует — она не найдёт файла, подпадающего под шаблон `*realplexor*.tar.gz`.

необходимо сделать что-нибудь одно из:

1. либо после скачивания переименовать файл `master` в, например, `realplexor.tar.gz`:

   ```
   $ mv master realplexor.tar.gz
   ```
2. либо добавить команде `wget ...` параметр `--content-disposition`, и тогда файл сразу получит имя `DmitryKoterov-dklab_realplexor-v1.41-7-g01281d4.tar.gz` (или что-то в этом роде).
3. либо распаковывать файл `master` не приведённой командой `tar ...`, а, например, так:

   ```
   $ cat master | gunzip | tar -x
   ```

после чего можно продолжать следовать инструкции.